# s there a way to track the last seq when using the all_docs endpoint in CouchDB

Tags: python, json, csv, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

Recently, a third-party company began providing data to us through CouchDB, and the responsibility of retrieving the data fell to me. At that time, I had read somewhere that it would be possible to retrieve changes using _changes with a date parameter. So, I saved the date and time in a file, thinking I could use this information to download the new data. However, I recently discovered that this approach is not feasible unless the documents themselves include a date.  Is there any way, perhaps using the rev field or another method, to obtain a lastseq based on that date or that data?

The solution I found was to download all the files again using _changes and then perform a diff between the old and new data. This way, I could capture the differences and start using the new lastseq from the latest generated data. But, the dataset is quite substantial, around 260 GB or more.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `_changes` plan you have, but without `include_docs` so you just get the keys and `_rev`s. Then, from your diff you want to get any `key` whose `_rev` has advanced from the data you already downloaded. Then you can use the [POST /{db}/_all_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#post--db-_all_docs) with the `include_docs` and pass in just the keys of the docs from your diff (ie. the ones you know have changed).